# Pagestyle of KOMA letter package

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, letters

I'm using the KOMA `scrletter` package to embed a letter into another document, see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrletter}

\rohead{My heading \\ Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstr. 12 \\ 12345~Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject ..}

\begin{letter}{Martina Musterfrau \\ Musterweg 4 \\ 12346~Musterdorf}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

The surrounding `scrartcl` document uses an own pagestyle with individual header, defined with `\rohead{...}`.

However, on the letter page, the header is not displayed.

How can I make the original header to display on all pages, especially on the letter page?

Comment: pagestyle `letter`, pagestyle of first page is `empty`. Use `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` after `\opening`.

Comment: Use `\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` after `\opening` and may be \setkomavar{firsthead}{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `scrletter` loads package `scrlayer-scrpage` and sets page style `scrheadings` for the document. Additionally new page styles `letter` and `plain.letter` are defined. Default for all letter pages except the first letter page is `plain.letter` that only prints `\letterpagemark`.

To change the page style for the pages (except the first page) in the `letter` environment you can use

```
\renewcommand\letterpagestyle{<page style>}
```

As page style you could use `letter`. Then the KOMA-Script variables `nexthead` and `nextfoot` define the content of the header and footer on the next pages. You can also use `scrheadings` as `<page style>`.

But note that the header and footer on the first page of the letter are not set by a page style. Therefore `\opening` uses `\thispagestyle{empty}`. So you have to remove the normal header and footer on the first page using options

```
firsthead=false,
firstfoot=false
```

and to use

```
\opening{...}
\thispagestyle{<page style>}
```

to get the `<page style>` on the first letter page too.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
  firsthead=false,
  firstfoot=false
]{scrletter}

\rohead{My heading \\ Max Mustermann}
\renewcommand\letterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstr. 12 \\ 12345~Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject ..}

\begin{letter}{Martina Musterfrau \\ Musterweg 4 \\ 12346~Musterdorf}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\Blindtext
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Instead `\opening{...}\thispagestyle{<page style>}` you could also patch `\opening`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}{}{}
```